# Azure: Is it possible to configure reverse proxy on nodejs based Azure app service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, reverse-proxy

I have 2 app service created in azure.
1st app service is nodejs runtime stack  which has nextjs based frontend app and 2nd app service is .net runtime stack which has .net core api deployed.

both application works individually.

https://myapp-frontend.azurewebsite.net
https://myapp-api.azurewebsite.net

Is it possible to create reverse for api so that i can have api rewrite from frontend route?

something like this.

https://myapp-frontend.azurewebsite.net  -> Frontend
https://myapp-frontend.azurewebsite.net/api  -> Apis

I have tried adding applicationhost.xdt file to make ARR active.

I have also created virtual application with /api sub domain and here is the web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://myapp-api.azurewebsite.net/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
            <outboundRules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyOutboundRule1" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match filterByTags="A, Area, Base, Form, Frame, Head, IFrame, Img" pattern="^http(s)?://NiceGateway/(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="http{R:1}://myapp-api.azurewebsite.net/NiceGateway/{R:2}" />
                </rule>
                <preConditions>
                    <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
                        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
                    </preCondition>
                </preConditions>
            </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

After making all these changes and restarting app service, I still get 404 file not found for api calls.
example:
https://myapp-frontend.azurewebsite.net/api/user/login  --> fails with 404